# magento1.9: 502 bad gateway when saving shipping addresses

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-address

I'm trying to save shipping address in my `Magento` form, but When I got **502 Bad gateway** error happening.
my shipping address code

```
      protected function saveAddress($oid)
{

   $order= Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($oid);
    $cusId = $order->getCustomerId();
    $cus = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($cusId);
    $ShipAdd = $order->getshipping();
    $shipping = Mage::getModel("customer/address")->setId($cus->getDefaultShipping());
    $shipping->setCustomerId($cus->getId());
    $shipping->setPrefix($ShipAdd->getPrefix());
    $shipping->setFirstname($ShipAdd->getFirstname());
    $shipping->setLastname($ShipAdd->getLastname());
    $shipping->setCountryId(self::BE_COUNTRY_CODE);
    $shipping->setPostcode($ShipAdd->getPostcode());
    $shipping->setCity($ShipAdd->getCity());
    $shipping->setStreet($ShipAdd->getStreet());
    $shipping->setTelephone($ShipAdd->getTelephone());

     try {
        $shipping->save();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
    }
    }
```

Any help will be appreciate

Answer (score 0):

I think the error because of the variable **$order** you used in

```
$cusId = $order->getCustomerId();
```

is not defined.

Replace below line

```
$oid = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($oid);
```

To

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($oid);
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: that is not a issue

Comment: Please check https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/resolving-502-bad-gateway-errors/  If it help you

Comment: Hypernode is a server provider, the above link is just for troubleshooting of your issue.

Comment: my server not having /var/log/php-fpm/php-fpm.log file